# reg-expression : word boundary with \t \n \r

Tags: regex

Best

I'm looking for a regex expression which will map if the word isn't a sub-word.
logically this might be possible via word boundaries: 
`\bHelloWorld\b`

but, they do not work when there is a `\t` or `\n` in the text.
e.g.:

```
HelloWorld is a beautiful word\nHelloWorld\t\t\tHelloWorld HelloWorld \t HelloWorld nopHelloWorld  HelloWorldnop \tnopHelloWorld ...
```

Thus in the above example, i would like to find 5 HelloWorld's

extra-info: the \n \t \r are respectively : new line, tab and carriage return
 (thus no 2 individual characters)

Comment: Is `\t` and `\n` two-char combinations with a backslash and a letter or tab/newline chars? If they are whitespace, you [get all 5 matches](https://regex101.com/r/Nyz0Di/1)

Comment: If they're really newline, tab, and CR characters, then `\b` should work.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - they are tab and newline chars,  (thus no 2 individual characters)

Comment: Then [your regex works](https://regex101.com/r/Nyz0Di/1).

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: @Barmar - python  (but i often test on regex101)

Comment: So, `print(text)` != `text` in the console

Comment: On regex101 you need to replace the escape sequences with the control characters in the test string.

Comment: Your regex works fine in python 3 https://rextester.com/MVMTU64628

Comment: @Barmar  i didn't wrote  r'   '

Comment: regex101 doesn't parse the `TEST STRING` box as a Python string literal, escape sequences are not processed there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python is going to interpolate an escaped control characters if is not a raw string.
So this is the parse result when not a raw string ( this one is single quoted ):

```
>>> print ('HelloWorld is a beautiful word\nHelloWorld\t\t\tHelloWorld HelloWorld \t HelloWorld nopHelloWorld  HelloWorldnop \tnopHelloWorld ...')
HelloWorld is a beautiful word
HelloWorld                      HelloWorld HelloWorld    HelloWorld nopHelloWorld  HelloWorldnop    nopHelloWorld ...
```

Which matches 5 hello world as is expected https://regex101.com/r/8TwxCO/1

But, if the original string is a *raw* string, then it will only match 3 https://regex101.com/r/nUdSZQ/1

```
>>> print (r'HelloWorld is a beautiful word\nHelloWorld\t\t\tHelloWorld HelloWorld \t HelloWorld nopHelloWorld  HelloWorldnop \tnopHelloWorld ...')
HelloWorld is a beautiful word\nHelloWorld\t\t\tHelloWorld HelloWorld \t HelloWorld nopHelloWorld  HelloWorldnop \tnopHelloWorld ...
```